# Overwrite results of one function with another

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple encoder-decoder game which encodes and decodes user-entered word as shown below:

> eg. **overflow --> ofvleorw --> overflow** (userword --> encodedword
>   --> decodedword).

The issue I'm having is that the encoder part works fine but when clicking decode button, the **developer tools crashes after few seconds**. I am unsure what the real issue is as I see **no error messages** on console so my only guess is the title heading.

> **Thank You and Happy New Year 2017**

```js
function encoder(){
 var userWord = document.getElementById("userinputbox").value; // gets user entered word
 var letterArray = userWord.split("");
 var encodedWord = [];
 for (var i=0; i<letterArray.length/2; i++) {
  encodedWord.push(letterArray[i],letterArray[letterArray.length/2 + i]);
 }  // pushing elements sequentially from first and second half of original array to new empty array
 displayResult.value = encodedWord.join("");
}

function decoder() {
 var encodedWord = displayResult.value; // extracts the encoded text from display box
 var letterArray = encodedWord.split("");
 var half1 = [], half2 = []; // array for storing even and odd index elements from letterArray
 for (var i=0; i<letterArray.length; i+2) {
  half1.push(letterArray[i]);
  half2.push(letterArray[i+1]);
 }
 var decodedWord = half1.concat(half2);
 displayResult.value = decodedWord.join(""); // overwriting the displaybox with new string
}

var displayResult = document.getElementById('displaybox'); // box to show results
var encodeBtn = document.getElementById('encode'); // event-listener 'Encode' btn
encodeBtn.addEventListener("click", encoder);
var decodeBtn = document.getElementById('decode'); // event-listener 'Decode' btn
decodeBtn.addEventListener("click", decoder);
```

```html
<body>
 Enter word (even number of letters) :<input type="text" id="userinputbox"><br>
 <input type="button" value="Encode" id="encode">
 <input type="button" value="Decode" id="decode">
 Results :<input type="text" id="displaybox" value="">
</body>
```

Comment: The `i+2` doesn’t change `i`. You need something like `i += 2`.

Comment: oh god you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is infinite: `for (var i=0; i<letterArray.length; i+2)`

You probably wanted something like `i = i + 2` in the end.

Whenever JS dies and you don't see an error, it's likely an infinite loop happening somewhere.
Happy new year !

Comment: yup my bad there not putting i+=2. oh and i learned today that if dev tools crashes, it must be infinite loop issues xD.cheers!!